# ggmap::get_map doesn't allow the exact specification of my map's corners?

Tags: r, ggmap

I am using R package ggmap.

`?get_map` says:

> location: an address, longitude/latitude pair (in that order), or
>   left/bottom/right/top bounding box

My code:

```
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)

lat_bottom = 52.33  # bottom latitude of Berlin
lat_top    = 52.5   # top latitude of Berlin
lon_left   = 13.0   # left longitude of Berlin
lon_rigth  = 13.95  # right longitude of Berlin

mymap <- get_map(location = c(lon_left,lat_bottom,lon_rigth,lat_top),
source="google")
ggmap(mymap)
```

Why is it giving me a warning:

> Warning: bounding box given to google - spatial extent only
>   approximate. converting bounding box to center/zoom specification.
>   (experimental)

Does it mean that there is no way for me to create a map with these
exact corners?

Based on the advice below I tried this:

```
lat_bottom = 52.33  # bottom latitude of Berlin
lat_top    = 52.68   # top latitude of Berlin
lon_left   = 13.08   # left longitude of Berlin
lon_rigth  = 13.77  # right longitude of Berlin

mylon = c(lon_left,lon_rigth)
mylat = c(lat_bottom,lat_top)

mymap <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(mylon), lat = mean(mylat)),
               maptype = "roadmap", source = "google", zoom=11) # using zoom
ggmap(mymap)
foo<-ggmap(mymap)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(lon_left,lon_right), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(lat_bottom,lat_top), expand = c(0, 0))
foo
```

It looks OK. But when I take other coordinates (those closer to each other), for example, like those below - then the map looks weird - it kinda shifts to the left on the gray background...

```
lat_bottom = 52.35  # new bottom
lat_top    = 52.50  # new top
lon_left   = 13.2   # new left
lon_rigth  = 13.5   # new right
```

Comment: You can get a map with a certain zoom. If you use `ggplot2`, you can trim the map using `scale_x_continous` and `scale_y_continous`. Have a look of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636897/get-map-with-specified-boundary-coordinates/25639124#25639124). This may be what you are after.

Comment: Just to clarify my objective: I am trying to avoid using "zoom". I don't know in advance (when I write the code) what area of the map I want to see. Sometimes it's larger, sometimes it's smaller. This is why I have to grab the 4 corners from the data and then try to draw a map with those corners.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to work with boundaries, it is better to use OpenStreetMap than GoogleMaps. Setting boundaries for GoogleMaps in `ggmap` doesn't work. Instead it will make an estimate of the centerpoint.

You can specify the source by including `source = "osm"` in your `get_map` call.

With:

```
mymap <- get_map(location = c(13.2,52.35,13.5,52.50), source = "osm")

ggmap(mymap)
```

you get:

[image]

Comment: "osm" doesn't seem to work anymore, there is some problem with the API.