# ggmap extended zoom or boundaries

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, coordinates, ggmap

I am trying to fix the following problem.
I use ggplot2 to plot a map of an island:

```
island = get_map(location = c(lon = -63.247593, lat = 17.631598), zoom = 14, maptype = "satellite")
islandMap = ggmap(island, extent = "panel", legend = "bottomright")
RL = geom_point(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), data = data, size = 4, color = "#ff0000")
islandMap + RL
```

Coordinates of the RL points:

```
data = data.frame(
    ID = as.numeric(c(1:8)),
    longitude = as.numeric(c(-63.27462, -63.26499, -63.25658, -63.2519, -63.2311, -63.2175, -63.23623, -63.25958)),
    latitude = as.numeric(c(17.6328, 17.64614, 17.64755, 17.64632, 17.64888, 17.63113, 17.61252, 17.62463))
)
```

Now the problem is that when I use zoom = 13 the island is too small in the plot and when I use zoom = 14 it is perfectly centered. But when I plot the RL points, two get cut off because its too much to the East and the other one too much to the West. I looked some solutions up like the following one, using a boundary box. However, I am bound to using satellite imagery, so bound to Google, which doesn't support the boundary box solution.

```
lon = data$longitude
lat = data$latitude
box = make_bbox(lon, lat, f = 0.1)
island = get_map(location = box, zoom = 14, source = "osm")
islandMap = ggmap(island, extent = "panel", legend = "bottomright")
RL = geom_point(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), data = data, size = 4, color = "#ff0000")
islandMap + RL
```

How can I make sure that the map is as big as using zoom = 14, all the points are within the plot (plus a margin around this) and satellite imagery?

Comment: you should use dput() for your Coordinates of the RL points:

Comment: I mean we can't reproduce your graphic because we don't have access to RL but if you use dput() we will. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited the coordinates, now included the DF 'data' with the coordinates in it. That should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using my answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636897/get-map-with-specified-boundary-coordinates/25639124#25639124), I did the following. You may want to get a map with zoom = 13, and then you want to trim the map with `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous()`.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

island = get_map(location = c(lon = -63.247593, lat = 17.631598), zoom = 13, maptype = "satellite")


RL <- read.table(text = "1    17.6328    -63.27462
2    17.64614   -63.26499
3    17.64755   -63.25658
4    17.64632   -63.2519
5    17.64888   -63.2311
6    17.63113   -63.2175
7    17.61252   -63.23623
8    17.62463   -63.25958", header = F)

RL <- setNames(RL, c("ID", "Latitude", "Longitude"))


ggmap(island, extent = "panel", legend = "bottomright") +
geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), data = RL, size = 4, color = "#ff0000") +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-63.280, -63.20), expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(17.60, 17.66), expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: how about the legend?