# cannot get the google satelite image with a bounding box

Tags: r, ggmap

I want to extract google satellite images in r.

I actually manage to get my image using the coordinates but not with the bounding bx

first you need to get a google api key and register it 
then

```r
GE <- get_map(location = c(long =36.8595894, lat=-0.7688972) , 
    maptype = "satellite", zoom=18)
ggmap(GE)
```

This works

then i want to make a bounding box

```r
box<-make_bbox(c(36.8594652,36.8597136),c(-0.7691144,-0.7686799 ) )
GE <- get_map(box , 
    maptype = "satellite", source="google",
    zoom=18)
```

This however does not return a satellite image, why?
it seems to return a ggmap but not from google and it is not viewable with ggmap(GE)

Comment: So what does it return instead? Based on the docs for `get_googlemap`, it seems like Google requires a center and zoom, whereas Stamen can take a bounding box.

Comment: @camille, thanks a lot, you are right... my issue is that i am extracting the images for many different place with different size, so basically i need to make my scale dependent on the image size... let me dig into this now... thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Camille is right, it is just not an option ind get_googlemap, this is however not straight forward when just looking at vignette of the wrapper function get_map.

I found this post [ggmap extended zoom or boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158767/ggmap-extended-zoom-or-boundaries) that shows how to handle the boundaries and zoom with google image.