# ggmap in r - own bounding box

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying to make a map with my own borders of bounding box. But so far I failed every time.

First I tried to do it with function `get_map`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636897/get-map-with-specified-boundary-coordinates/25639124#25639124) I found that I need to specify `source = "osm"`. My code had been

```
 my_map<-get_map(location=c(-15, 30, 15, 85), source="osm")
```

but I recieved an error

```
 Error: map grabbing failed - see details in ?get_openstreetmap.
 In addition: Warning message:
 In download.file(url, destfile = destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb")      :
   cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (nil)'`
```

Than I tried using `get_openstreetmap`. My code was

```
  get_openstreetmap(bbox = c(left = -15.00000, bottom = 29.38048, right = 15.00000,
  top=85.00000, scale=606250))
```

but again I got an error

```
 Error: bounding box improperly specified.  see ?get_openstreetmap
```

Although I read both `?get_openstreetmap` and `?get_map` I dont know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me? Please consider that after getting a map I will need to add some `points` on it, so just `url` isn't enough for me.

Thx a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Couple of issues here. You have a typo thats including scale in your bounding box for the `get_openstreetmap` function, causing the error.

```
get_openstreetmap(bbox = c(left = -15.00000, bottom = 29.38048, right = 15.00000,
  top=85.00000), scale=606250)
```

Second the scale you're trying to download appears to be to small for the region your downloading. Try increasing the scale.

```
help(OSM_scale_lookup)
```