# ggmap plotted with bounding coordinates

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636897/get-map-with-specified-boundary-coordinates/25639124#25639124) for applying a bounding box of coordinates when plotting a ggmap, as specifying get_map() using a bounding box does not work (is converted to center and zoom).

However, I end up with a lot of extra gray around my plot. I would like to have a plot fitted nicely where the bounding coordinates are (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) = (-170,-30, -60, 110)

```
# Get a Google satellite map of North and South America
map <- get_map(location = c(-100, 20), zoom = 2, maptype = "satellite", source = "google")
ggmap(map)
```

The result is: [image: this map]

I would like to have a plot fitted to the coordinates described above.

```
# Attempt to scale the x and y axes
ggmap(map) + 
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-170, -30), expand=c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-60, 110), expand=c(0,0))
```

What I end up with is a plot that looks like this: [image]

Cropped nicely but with excessive gray space at the top.

Edit: I used R 3.3.3 in RStudio 1.0.136, with ggmap 2.7 and ggplot2 2.2.0

Comment: When I run the code you provided, I don't have the extra gray space as you do. Have you tried restarting R? Are you running this in Rstudio? Try running it in the R terminal

Comment: @Tiffany Good questions. I was indeed running it in RStudio, using R 3.3.3. I tried it just now in R terminal, and had the same problem with gray space. I also restarted RStudio just now and tried it again, first plot of the session--same problem with the gray. Would you mind telling me which R, ggmap, and ggplot2 versions you are running? (I should have put mine in the post!)

Comment: Works fine here (R 3.4.1, Rstudio latest)

Comment: I am using R terminal (3.4.1),  ggplot2 2.2.1, ggmap 2.6.1. Given what @Remko said, it looks like it might be your version of R

Comment: @LCM I had run your code on R 3.3.3 and R 3.4.0, and also under RStudio (OS: Windows7). No extra gray space.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work using R terminal 3.4.1, ggmap 2.6.1 (installed by default for that R version), and ggplot2 2.2.1 (installed by default). Does anybody know why it might be flaky across versions like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do exceeds the boundaries of the map. The maximum positive/negative `Latitude` on a mercator-style projection is `85.0511... / -85.0511...`, because
`arctan(sinh(Pi)) * 180 / Pi = 85.0511288`.

This code will yield a correct result:

```
ggmap(map, extent = "panel") + 
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-170, -30), expand=c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-60, 85), expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]